# Any Drawback to Using Tuples as Dictionary Keys in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Seems like there should be...

Right now it just seems like magic that you can hash multidimensionally to the same table, without any negative effects.

Comment: Life can indeed be that great :)

Comment: @SimeonVisser Anytime that I have a seemingly very challenging problem, it suddenly turns out that this is the magical solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the dictionary's perspective, there's not a single thing multi-dimensional about it. The dictionary has no idea that you are interpreting the keys as describing an n-space.

You could, for example, cleverly pack your vector into a string which would seem less magical, be more complicated to get right, and yet be functionally equivalent. Python strings are Yet Another Immutable Sequence as far as the interpreter is concerned.

There is no negative effect.

Some tasks might be less efficient than an alternate implementation. For example if you are using `(x, y, z)` coordinates as keys, finding all points at some `z` will be time consuming relative to a real multi-dimensional store. But sometimes clarity and ease of implementation and reading trump efficient store.

Comment: With all the time you saved setting up the primary `(x,y,z)` keyed dict, you can devise additional indexing schemes to speed up other tasks as you need them. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The only drawback is performance.  Larger keys mean longer times to hash.

Simply put, the only requirement of keys in a python dict is that they be immutable and hashable.  For tuples (which are immutable), this means that you just need to combine the hashes of the sub-objects (which themselves must be immutable and hashable).  You can also use a frozenset as a key.  You can't use lists or dicts or sets as keys.

Comment: I tried a quick and dirty benchmark comparing dict insert and lookup with tuple-of-3-integer versus plain integer keys. tuples took about 13% more time in the insert and 16% more time in the lookup. That's not counting the time to create the tuple keys themselves - I prebuilt a list of keys for the tests. So it makes a difference, but not an enormous one.